# ConnectionFactory exception Camel testing JMS

Tags: junit, jms

I'm doing my first steps with Camel and currently working on writing a simple junit test using jms as a transport.

Here is a code I wrote:

```
public class FirstMockTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("jms:topic:quote")
                        .to("mock:quote");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testMessageCount() throws InterruptedException {
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:quote");
        mockEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("jms:topic:quote", "Camel rocks");
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Because of missing connectionFactory I got the following exception:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[jms:topic:quote]] -> [To[mock:quote]]] because of connectionFactory must be specified
```

I'm able to fix it adding the following lines to my route:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
   new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?roker.persistent=false");
context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory));
```

But I don't like I'm adding some components to my context inside the route. Also, If i want to have another route I will need to do it again.
Obviously, there should be another way to tell my test about connection factory.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to define the JMS connection factory outside of your Camel context and, if possible, reuse it. How to do that depends on your component model / execution environment.

If you're using a Java SE version that supports **CDI**, that would be an obvious choice. You'd define your JMS connection factory as a named component once and inject it everywhere you need it. Have a look at http://camel.apache.org/cdi.html and for testing support at http://camel.apache.org/cdi-testing.html

If you're using **Spring**, define your connection factory as a spring bean and inject it wherever you need it.

If you're using **Java EE** on an application server, you'd usually define the JMS connection factory using the mechanisms of that app server. You'd then look up the JMS connection factory using JNDI.

If you're running in an **OSGi** container, you should define the JMS connection factory in its own bundle and export it as an OSGi service. In the bundle of your Camel context, import that OSGi servide and inject it into the Camel context.

In all above cases you should consider using a pooled JMS connection factory.

For CDI, Spring and OSGi, have a look at: http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.14.5/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/jms/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html

For Java EE the way how to set pooling parameters depends on your app server.

Note of caution: for Java SE CDI and Spring there should be only one Camel context per application (you can have many routes, though). So if the JMS connection factory is only used in that one Camel context, there is not much reuse. Despite that I still think it's preferable to define the JMS connection outside of the Camel context in a separate component. It's, well, cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a junit you can avoid creating a ConnectionFactory if you stub the jms endpoint. You can name the endpoint as stub:jms:topic:quote. Have a look at sample example at link https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter9/mock/src/test/java/camelinaction/FirstMockTest.java